# How to find the center point and border of the image inside an ImageView

Tags: android, image, imageview

There is an ImageView and it has an Image, which has been zoomed and rotated.

See the picture:

[image]

The image is scaled by `android.graphics.Matrix`.

You can see there is red point which is the center point of the image, and also a blue border. How to calculate them?

(Update: I want to operate on the image of the girl inside the blue border, not the whole picture, that's background)

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Which image do you want to process? The whole image, or just the image enclosed with the blue border and with a girl inside?

Comment: The image with blue border and a girl inside :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mathematical dependency between two. If there is other information available:
-assuming rectangle has right angles for all corners-.

```
center.X = (aCorner.X + oppositeCorner.X)/2;
center.Y = (aCorner.Y + oppositeCorner.Y)/2;
```

Where aCorner is a arbitrary corner and oppositeCorner is opposite corner to aCorner.

This was trivial,  a little more hard work included to calculate borders (and a bit more of information; center position, width and the height of the picture and rotation angle).
Assuming image's width is "w", height is "h", angle is "a", and center "cX" and "cY".
First corner;

```
length = sqrt(w^2+h^2)/2;
x = (length)*(cos(a)*(-w/length) - (h/length)*sin(a)) + cX;
y = (length)*(sin(a)*(-w/length) + (h/length)*cos(a)) + cY;
```

Second corner;

```
x = (length)*(cos(a)*(w/length) + sin(a)*(h/length)) + cX;
y = (length)*(cos(a)*(h/length) - sin(a)*(w/length)) + cY;
```

Third;

```
x = -(length)*(cos(a)*(-w/length) + (h/length)*sin(a)) + cX;
y = -(length)*(sin(a)*(-w/length) - (h/length)*cos(a)) + cY;
```

Fourth;

```
x = -(length)*(cos(a)*(w/length) - sin(a)*(h/length)) + cX;
y = (length)*(cos(a)*(h/length) - sin(a)*(w/length)) + cY;
```

Length is a half of diagonal of the rectangle. The inner part with cos and sin is result of trigonometric transformation:

```
sin(a+b) = sin(a)*cos(b) + cos(a)*sin(b)
[....]
```

And cX and cY is used to translate corners from a arbitrary coordinate system to a specific coordinate system.

I know, I know this was kind of overkill. Matrix class may have this functions on its own. I believe if it has, the method used in it can be broken into method I described here.

NOTE: Angle a -actually even sin(a) and cos(a), which is better- can be accessed via
Matrix.getValues(float[] values)

Most 2D matrices use this scheme:

```
| sin(a) 0       0    |
| 0      -cos(a) 0    |
| 0      0       scale|
```

I am not sure about particular implementation of Android API.

BTW, there may have been some signature errors up there so be careful.

Comment: Thanks for mathematical answer. I also want to know how to use android APIs to get those points(4 corners) of the image inside a scaled ImageView.

Comment: I am not sure if API deploys that feature. Because translation/transformation matrices are mostly used only with one-way to edit. But my advice is to paint what you want to paint when there is no matrix on the bitmap. And THEN set the matrix.